# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on null in system/library/user.php

Tags: php

```
 public function login($username, $password) {

        $user_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user WHERE username = '" . $this->db->escape($username) . "' AND (password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('" . $this->db->escape($password) . "'))))) OR password = '" . $this->db->escape(md5($password)) . "') AND status = '1'");

        if ($user_query->num_rows) {
            $this->session->data['user_id'] = $user_query->row['user_id'];    
            $this->user_id = $user_query->row['user_id'];
            $this->username = $user_query->row['username'];
            $this->user_group_id = $user_query->row['user_group_id'];
            $user_group_query = $this->db->query("SELECT permission FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user_group WHERE user_group_id = '" . (int)$user_query->row['user_group_id'] . "'");    
            $permissions = json_decode($user_group_query->row['permission'], true);    
            if (is_array($permissions)) {
                foreach ($permissions as $key => $value) {
                    $this->permission[$key] = $value;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }      
        else {
            return false;
        }
}
```

while using this function, i am getting Fatal error:  Call to a member function query() on null in /system/library/user.php

Comment: Same function with different table name works fine for customer, This is a admin authentication api.

Comment: check your query, it is not closed properly

Comment: what's wrong with it, it is closed properly i guess, There is something wrong with query which i am unable to figure it out

Comment: Did you load $this->load->db() inn your constructor?

Comment: while loading db as you said, it is giving me " Undefined property: User::$load in"

Comment: try this `$this->load->database()`

Comment: no luck!! still reproducing that error

Comment: are you using any frame work ?

Comment: yes , This is in rest api                                                                                                           Location: public_html/foldernane/system/library/user.php                                                 Do i need to autoload db ,somewhere else i dont know where to find autoload.php

Answer (score 0):

The error "**Call to a member function query() on null**" clearly indicates that you have not initialised **db** variable to a mysql connection or failed due to invalid credential.

Make sure it is initialized in constructor on first place.

Comment: Please post your entire class for more clarity & precise answer.

Comment: public function __construct($registry) {
  $this->db = $registry->get('db');
  $this->request = $registry->get('request');
  $this->session = $registry->get('session');                                           This is My constructor

Comment: use **global $registry;**
Your code will look like :
public function __construct() {
        global $registry;
        $this->db = $registry->get('db');
        $this->request = $registry->get('request');
        $this->session = $registry->get('session');
    }

Comment: i tried but it is still giving me Call to a member function query() on null in

Comment: check your mysql credential on test project. Using this code :
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

Comment: Connection is ok!! , i am calling same function from different file , that is working fine,hope it makes sense